# Where does that space come from between the radio button and label from flutter dev site?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html

I copy/pasted the author radio button sample into my app and this is how it looks like:

[image]

My Code:

```
 return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(child: ListTile(
          title: const Text('Left radio button'),
          leading: Radio(
            value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
            groupValue: _character,
            onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
              setState(() {
                _character = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),),
        Expanded(child: ListTile(
          title: Text('right radio button'),
          leading: Radio(
            value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
            groupValue: _character,
            onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
              setState(() {
                _character = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        )],
    );
```

How can I remove the spaces/margins that I painted as red line on the image?
I can not find these margins anywhere in my code...

The image was taken with Dart Dev Tools and "Select Widget Mode" was turned on that you can see the spaces around the elements radio and label.

Or is it just better to create my own radio button group... ? There is also still the problem that the radio can`t be selected with a clicked label...

Comment: you can give `materialTapTargetSize` the value `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` that will reduce the extra space it is taking, however it won't remove all the extra space.

Comment: It seems shrinkwrap is the default. Because setting it explicit changed NOTHING. :-) just PADDED made the radio lots bigger.

Comment: then I don't think you can do anything other than create your own custom widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `flutter\lib\src\material\list_tile.dart` you can find

> static const double _horizontalTitleGap = 16.0;

So its basically hardcoded that *'The horizontal gap between the titles and the leading/trailing widgets'*.

We cannot override this. But we can just use `Row` in `title`

Try this,

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio(
              value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            const Text('Left radio button'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio(
              value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text('right radio button'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: do you not get an error  for each radio title element that to the right side its overlapping?

Comment: I still added for the ListTile this:             contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
to get rid of the default space on the sides... but ListTile is good to use here because it has onTap where I can do setState() to change the radio button state when clicking anywhere on the ListTile (radio OR label).

Answer (score 5):

you can use `ListTileTheme` and set horizontalTitleGap with the value you want the defualt is 16 so you can just made it like that

`ListTileTheme( horizontalTitleGap: 2, child: RadioListTile<...>( value: ...`

Comment: Best answer. Did the trick

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might come here looking for answers. The easiest way to achieve this is by wrapping the `Radio` **without** any padding, in a `Container` and then setting your custom `Margin` and `Padding` as(if) required.

Here is an example:

```
Container(
  height: 10, //Make it equal to height of radio button
  width: 10,  //Make it equal to width of radio button
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),  //Apply margins and(or) paddings as per requirement
  child: Radio(
    value: value,
    groupValue: groupValue,
    onChanged: (value) {
      // Task you want to perform on radio button click
    },        
  ),
)
```

Comment: This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [RadioListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html) widget. It has a property called VisualDensity with which you can define the compactness of the RadioTile. This ranges between -4 to 4, -4 being most compact.

eg:

```html
RadioListTile<int>(
          contentPadding: edgeInsets0,
          // Visual Density passed here
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4.0),
          dense: true,
          activeColor: primaryColor,
          selectedTileColor: primaryColor,
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .subtitle1!
                .copyWith(color: darkHeadingTextColor),
          ),
          value: value,
          groupValue: groupValue,
          onChanged: (int? value) {

          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to reduce the gap is as below :

```
ListTileTheme(   // <-- add this
  horizontalTitleGap: 0,   // <-- add this
  child: RadioListTile<dynamic>(
    visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4.0),   // <-- add this
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,   // <-- add this
    dense: true,   // <-- add this if necessary
    title: ...,
    value: ...,
    groupValue: ...,
    onChanged: (value) { ... },
    selected: ...,
  ),
)
```

Use horizontalTitleGap,visualDensity,contentPadding with respective minimum values.